# RecyclerView reusing algorithm

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an `Adapter` with multiple view types. 
I have noticed that `onCreateViewHolder()` gets called quite often even though `onCreateViewHolder()` , `onBindViewHolder()` and `getItemViewType()` are implemented correctly.

For instance my RecyclerView should display a simple list of different items like this and lets assume that all items have the same view height and that 6 elements fill the whole Screen (matches the height of RecyclerView):

```
> ViewType0
> ViewType0
> ViewType0
> ViewType0
> ViewType0
> ViewType1
> ViewType2
> ViewType2
> ViewType2
> ViewType2
> ViewType1    
> ViewType1
> ViewType1
> ViewType0
> ViewType0
> ViewType0
```

While scrolling and reaching the end of the list it seems that for the last two items (`ViewType0`) RecyclerView calls `onCreateViewHolder()` but from my point of view the recyclerview should recycle (reuse) the already existing one (there are 5 at the top of the list which are not visibile) rather than recreating two new for the last two items.

Is that behaviour normal? Are the settings I can apply to avoid the recreation of new ViewHolder because there should be definitely reusable ViewHolders (from top of the list)?

Comment: Good point. I've noticed that too.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely normal. I'll explain briefly how it works.

As soon as any view is scrolled out of the window, RecyclerView has two options: to recycle or to reuse that view. It determines what option to choose by simply compares the viewType of the next item that's appearing next with your scrolled-out view; if they're the same, simply reuse the view, and vice versa.

In your case, those 5 ViewType0 views are most certainly recycled long time before the last two ViewType0 views are set to appear, so the only way for it to show the view is to recreate it.